# Efficient way to modify an Array of Objects

Tags: javascript

I have an object which i need to reformat. The input array looks like this.
I would like to reformat it in a better way than using nested loops

```js
[{
    CategoryId,
    CategoryName,
    CustomerDescription_c,
    CategoryShortName,
    CategoryCode,
    subcomponents: {
        items: [
            {
                CategoryId,
                CategoryName,
                CustomerDescription_c,
                CategoryShortName,
                CategoryCode
            }
        ]
    }
}]
```

I would like to manipulate this array of objects into this format.

```js
[{
    CategoryId,
    CategoryName,
    CustomerDescription_c,
    CategoryShortName,
    CategoryCode,
    ParentLevel,
    hasChildren,
    value // to populate conditionally if above corresponding object does not have subcomponent 
    children :  [
            {
                CategoryId,
                CategoryName,
                CustomerDescription_c,
                CategoryShortName,
                CategoryCode,
                value : 'Parent CategoryId',to populate conditionally if above corresponding parent object has subcomponent
                ParentLevel
            }
        ]
}]
```

To do this i have the below function where i use a nested loop but would like to know if there is a better algorithm to do the same thing

```js
function (data) {
    let formattedData = [];
      if (data) {
        let arr = data;
        for (let i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
            let category = {
                CategoryId: arr[i].CategoryId,
                CategoryName: arr[i].CategoryName,
                CustomerDescription_c: arr[i].CustomerDescription_c,
                CategoryShortName: arr[i].CategoryShortName,
                CategoryCode: arr[i].CategoryCode,
                ParentLevel: true
            };
            if (arr[i].subcomponents) {
                let childrenArray = arr[i].subcomponents.items;
                category.children = [];
                category.hasChildren = true;
                for (let j = 0, len = childrenArray.length; j < len; j++) {
                    category.children.push({
                      CategoryId: childrenArray[j].CategoryId,
                      CategoryName: childrenArray[j].CategoryName,
                      CustomerDescription_c: childrenArray[j].CustomerDescription_c,
                      CategoryShortName: childrenArray[j].CategoryShortName,
                      value: arr[i].CategoryId,
                      CategoryCode: childrenArray[j].CategoryCode,
                      ParentLevel: false
                    });
                }
            } else {
                category.value = arr[i].CategoryId;
                category.hasChildren = false;
            }
            formattedData.push(category);
        }
      }
      return formattedData;
  };
```

Comment: Probably a lot better to use a recursive function. as the children have the same structure as the parent. Destructuring and assignment will save you a lot of complexities as well, as will `Array.map`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function `transform` that does a simple type analysis on it's input, `t` -

```js
function transform (t, parentId = null) {
  switch (t?.constructor) {
    case Array:
      return t.map(v => transform(v, parentId))
    case Object:
      const { subcomponents = {}, ...node } = t
      return {
        ...node,
        parentId,
        hasChildren: Boolean(subcomponents.items),
        children: transform(subcomponents.items ?? [], t.id)
      }
    default:
      throw Error()
  }
}
```

Given some starting `data`-

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, category: "a", subcomponents: {
    items: [
      { id: 2, category: "a1", subcomponents: {
        items: [
          { id: 3, category: "a1z" }
        ]
      }},
      { id: 1, category: "a2", subcomponents: {
        items: [
          { id: 4, category: "a2x" },
          { id: 5, category: "a2y" }
        ]
      }},
    ]
  }},
  { id: 6, category: "b", subcomponents: {
    items: [
      { id: 7, category: "bb", subcomponents: {
        items: [
          { id: 8, category: "bbb", subcomponents: {
            items: [
              { id: 9, category: "bbbb" }
            ]
          }},
        ]
      }},
    ]
  }},
  { id: 10, category: "z", subcomponents: {
    items: [
      { id: 11, category: "z" }
    ]
  }},
]
```

```js
transform(data)
```

```js
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "category": "a",
    "parentId": null,
    "hasChildren": true,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "category": "a1",
        "parentId": 1,
        "hasChildren": true,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "category": "a1z",
            "parentId": 2,
            "hasChildren": false,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "category": "a2",
        "parentId": 1,
        "hasChildren": true,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 4,
            "category": "a2x",
            "parentId": 1,
            "hasChildren": false,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "id": 5,
            "category": "a2y",
            "parentId": 1,
            "hasChildren": false,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "category": "b",
    "parentId": null,
    "hasChildren": true,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 7,
        "category": "bb",
        "parentId": 6,
        "hasChildren": true,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 8,
            "category": "bbb",
            "parentId": 7,
            "hasChildren": true,
            "children": [
              {
                "id": 9,
                "category": "bbbb",
                "parentId": 8,
                "hasChildren": false,
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "category": "z",
    "parentId": null,
    "hasChildren": true,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 11,
        "category": "z",
        "parentId": 10,
        "hasChildren": false,
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

<kbd>Run</kbd> the demo below to verify the result in your own browser -

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, category: "a", subcomponents: {
    items: [
      { id: 2, category: "a1", subcomponents: {
        items: [
          { id: 3, category: "a1z" }
        ]
      }},
      { id: 1, category: "a2", subcomponents: {
        items: [
          { id: 4, category: "a2x" },
          { id: 5, category: "a2y" }
        ]
      }},
    ]
  }},
  { id: 6, category: "b", subcomponents: {
    items: [
      { id: 7, category: "bb", subcomponents: {
        items: [
          { id: 8, category: "bbb", subcomponents: {
            items: [
              { id: 9, category: "bbbb" }
            ]
          }},
        ]
      }},
    ]
  }},
  { id: 10, category: "z", subcomponents: {
    items: [
      { id: 11, category: "z" }
    ]
  }},
]

function transform (t, parentId = null) {
  switch (t?.constructor) {
    case Array:
      return t.map(v => transform(v, parentId))
    case Object:
      const { subcomponents = {}, ...node } = t
      return {
        ...node,
        parentId,
        hasChildren: Boolean(subcomponents.items),
        children: transform(subcomponents.items ?? [], t.id)
      }
    default:
      throw Error()
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(transform(data), null, 2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

I renamed `value` to `parentId` as it is more descriptive. And I would advise against `hasChildren: Boolean` key/value as it is derived state and does not need to be stored in each node. We can know whether or not any particular node has children by checking the `.children` property.